# posting content of csv file to Jira using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, jira-rest-api

There is some requirement in which content of a csv file need to be posted as a comment on a Jira ticket using PowerShell. When I use simple text it works perfectly but with csv file content it gives escape sequence related errors.

Below is the code-snippet which I am using for the same: -

```
$restApiUri = "https://jira.HereMyDomainName.com/rest/api/2/"
$issueKey = "MyIssueNumberGoesHere"
$comment = Import-Csv c:\Test\result.csv "|" | ConvertTo-Json
$body = ('{"body": "'+$comment+'"}')

Invoke-RestMethod -uri ($restApiUri +"issue/$issueKey/comment") -Headers $headers -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

My result.csv file content is in below format: -

```
QueryDate|SEQID|MSG_ID|MSG_VER
08/21/2018 15:18:49|571123552|16952_15613|1
08/21/2018 15:18:49|571123553|16952_14973|1
```

And error is: -

> WARNING: The remote server response: {"errorMessages":["Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 13)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@77167eea; line: 1, column: 13]"]} BadRequest

Please help me to identify the mistake I am doing here or suggest me a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: [Control_character 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) is the carriage return. You will need to escape them before sending them as the error indicates.

Comment: Try `ConvertTo-Json -Compress`.  That should give you a single string with no carriage returns.  Also be advised that `ConvertTo-Json` uses Microsoft's .Net JSON serializer which has it's own notation for things like dates, and is incompatible with many web services.

Comment: I tried with -Compress too but no luck.

Comment: Does ``$comment = Import-Csv c:\Test\result.csv "|" | ConvertTo-Json -Compress; $comment.IndexOf("`n")`` return -1?  If not, you've got an embedded line ending somewhere in your CSV.  If it does return -1, try `Import-Csv c:\Test\result.csv "|" | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Clipboard` and validate it at [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/).  If that shows as valid, then you'll want to refer to the API documentation or try it with `curl.exe` because I don't think you're doing anything wrong with your JSON then.

Comment: $commen.IndexOf("`n") return -1. and Json is valid.

Comment: Carriage Return character (ASCII code 13) in PowerShell is `"\`r"`  NewLine character (ASCII code 10) in PowerShell is `"\`n"`

Comment: @theo Yh I tried with duo, but no luck. :(

Comment: Then.. What is in `$headers` ?